# Regex - nothing or anything longer then 3 chars before the given tag

Tags: .net, regex, string

I need to to make a regex for two string (`_london` and `_uk_london`)
if `_london` is detected then Action A is executed. if `_uk_london` is found then Action B is executed

My current Regex:

```
.*?_uk_london
.*?_london
```

the problem i'm currently facing is: `"how can i modify my regex so the string before the underscore is nothing or at least 3 chars long?"` I can split it into two regex's but i would like to find a solution than tackle this problem into a single regex.

Any pointers would be very welcome!

Thank you for your time

**Note**: The subtext('Uk' in this case) is always max 2 chars long

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a Regex that will match either `_london` or any character * 3 (or more) + `_london` :

`^(.{3,})?_london`

Note that the Group 1 will return either the code, or empty.

Test entries:

```
_uk_london
_london
_fra_london
sdfsdf_london
```

Results:

```
Match             $1
_uk_london        _uk   
_london     
_fra_london      _fra   
sdfsdf_london    sdfsdf
```

Visual version from http://regexper.com :

[image: Visual of the regex's behaviour]

Comment: You need to add ^ in the beginning.

Comment: Thnx man! you're a lifesaver! i just couldn't figure it out on my own :(